# Flask WTForm Integer Field - Add Validation from Route

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I am using Flask WTform Integer Field as follows:

```
class SellForm(FlaskForm):
    Sell_Amount = IntegerField('Sell_Amount', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=1)])
    submit = SubmitField('Sell')
```

I am trying to append a Number Range Validation in Route for Maximum amount

```
if request.method == 'GET':
    form.Sell_Amount.validators = [DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=1, max=Max_Amount)]
```

However, this method is not working

the max value can be determined in the following ways:

- available in route
- available as a parameter in the URL
- Dynamic and changing per use case (I can't set it in the Form Initialization Class

Any help in setting the validation dynamically in the route

thanks a lot

Setting the WTForm Dynamicaly from Route not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically Add or Remove WTForms validators in Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72598178/dynamically-add-or-remove-wtforms-validators-in-flask)

Comment: i tried the proposed solution and didnt work

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically create a form field including validators. The following example uses an outsourced function for this purpose.

```py
def form_factory(max_amount=1):
    class F(FlaskForm):
        submit = SubmitField('Sell')

    field = IntegerField('Sell Amount', 
        validators=[
            DataRequired(), 
            NumberRange(min=1, max=max_amount)
        ]
    )
    setattr(F, 'sell_amount', field)

    return F

@app.route('/sell', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sell():
    max_amount = request.args.get('amount', 1, type=int)
    form = form_factory(max_amount)(request.form)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        pass 
    return render_template('sell.html', **locals())
```